# API_EC_TOO_MANY_CALLS on Facebook API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

We are running an stress test on our application using 10 FB test users... After some time, we start to receive API error **API_EC_TOO_MANY_CALLS**, meaning that we are doing too many calls on the FB API servers...

On our Insights Page (Diagnostics), its showing:

**Calls Are Too CPU Intensive**

Method | Fraction of Budget

gr:get:User | 8,066%

gr:get/fql | 5,861%

gr:get:User/permissions | 496%

**Too Many Calls**

Method | Fraction of Budget

gr:get/fql | 18,171%

gr:get:User | 16,888%

gr:get:User/permissions | 1,520%

Yes, we are caching things and Yes we are using batch multiquery for FQL... Finally, yes, we already opened an “bug” ticket but no one answer us until now...

Does anyone here ever had this problem? Any help?

Thanks so much!

Comment: had the same problem. FB says that for app limit is 100M requests/day. But it started blocking API for my app at 800K requests.

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.fb-developers.info/tech/fb_dev/faq/general/gen_10.php for a good list of API errors and what they mean.

You should monitor for API_EC_RATE and start adding a wait timer for a second or so before attempting another FB API call.  If you do that, then you might not get the API_EC_TOO_MANY_CALLS error code.

Answer (score 0):

@DMCS 
This is interesting, thought I only see API_EC_TOO_MANY_CALLS in my logs. No API_EC_RATE return at all.
Do you know what is the rate that may lead to those errors?

Answer (score 0):

I Found that FB API limits depends from app MAU. 100m calls/dey is a maximum value for the maximum MAU.